# How to make Discord.js Bot responds with local picture when we mentions(@) the bot?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am a newbie to JavaScript. I want to make my discord server's bot responding with local picture on my computer while anybody mentions(@) it. I have tried multiple methods,
this is the one I follow the documentation:

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.mentions.has("My Bot's ID")) {
  const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./images/image1.png');
  return message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author},`, attachment);
 }
});
```

This one failed, as well as a few older version methods I tried. Some of them not even operate, so I deleted them.

Also, I can't find any other materials besides the documentation for the version(12.3.1).

Comment: this seems pretty straight foward, I have never built a bot on discord, but the code is fairly simple, when someone metions the bot it will trigger the function, from the conditional. To figure out mentions go here https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work

Answer (score 0):

[`MessageMentions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions) is an object. You are looking for the [`MessageMentions.users`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=users) Collection.

```js
client.on('message', (message) => {
 if (message.mentions.users.has("My Bot's ID")) {
  // message.mentions.users
  const attachment = new MessageAttachment('./images/image1.png');
  return message.channel.send(`Hi ${message.author},`, attachment);
 }
});
```